# Draw path around visible part of UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to draw a path around the visible part of a UIBezierPath?

Here's an example of my problem

[image: Here's an example of my problem]

Here's what I'd like to accomplish

[image: Here's what I'd like to accomplish]

Here's what I got so far:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGFloat side = MIN(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
  CGPoint center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2.0f, rect.size.height / 2.0f);

  UIColor *yinYangColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  UIBezierPath *yinYangPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

  // Draw Yin&Yang part
  [yinYangPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y - side / 4.0f) radius:side / 4.0f startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:-M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
  [yinYangPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y + side / 4.0f) radius:side / 4.0f startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:-M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];
  [yinYangPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y) radius:side / 2.0f startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
  [yinYangPath closePath];
  [yinYangColor setFill];
  [yinYangPath fill];

  // Add border
  CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
  borderLayer.path = yinYangPath.CGPath;
  borderLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
  borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  borderLayer.lineWidth = 5.0f;
  [self.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle π/2 radians is along the positive y axis.

In standard UIKit geometry, the positive y axis points down toward the bottom of the screen. Therefore the top arc (at `center.y - side/4`) needs to start at angle -π/2 and end at angle π/2. Since you got these backward, your second arc doesn't start where your first arc ended, so your path contains a straight line connecting those points. Ditto for your second and third arcs. The single straight line visible in your image is actually the combination of those two lines.

Also, incidentally, the `rect` passed to `drawRect:` is in theory not necessarily the bounds of the view. It's better not to treat it as such.

Also also, you shouldn't add sublayers in `drawRect:`. You should do that in `init` or `layoutSubviews` and you should make sure you don't duplicate layers. I guess maybe you're using a `CAShapeLayer` because you don't want the border cut off. I would solve that by insetting the view bounds by the border width:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {
    CGFloat lineWidth = 4;
    CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, lineWidth / 2, lineWidth / 2);
    CGFloat side = MIN(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGFloat smallRadius = side / 4;
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y - smallRadius) radius:smallRadius startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y + smallRadius) radius:smallRadius startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
    [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:side / 2 startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:-M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];
    [path closePath];
    [path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];
    [path setLineWidth:lineWidth];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [path fill];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Result:

[image: symbol]

If you want the bottom tip to be more pointy, I would do that by clipping all drawing to the path, then drawing the border twice as thick. Half the border will be drawn outside the path and clipped away, leaving a sharp point. In this case, you don't have to inset the bounds.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {
    CGFloat lineWidth = 4 * 2;
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    CGFloat side = MIN(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGFloat smallRadius = side / 4;
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y - smallRadius) radius:smallRadius startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y + smallRadius) radius:smallRadius startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
    [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:side / 2 startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:-M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];
    [path closePath];
    [path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];
    [path addClip];
    [path setLineWidth:lineWidth];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [path fill];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Result:
[image: pointier symbol]

Comment: Superb answer! Thank you so much @rob-mayoff !

Comment: If an answer helps you or solves your problem, please upvote it or click the check mark next to it to accept it, or both.